# Scrapy startproject doesn't work Permission denied: spiders

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

I successfully installed Scrapy.

I created a virtual environment on ubuntu which is on the new windows terminal.

when i try to create a new project i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/d/Scrapy/venv/bin/scrapy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/mnt/d/Scrapy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 143, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/mnt/d/Scrapy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 98, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/mnt/d/Scrapy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 151, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/mnt/d/Scrapy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/commands/startproject.py", line 110, in run
    self._copytree(self.templates_dir, abspath(project_dir))
  File "/mnt/d/Scrapy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/commands/startproject.py", line 83, in _copytree
    self._copytree(srcname, dstname)
  File "/mnt/d/Scrapy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/commands/startproject.py", line 83, in _copytree
    self._copytree(srcname, dstname)
  File "/mnt/d/Scrapy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/commands/startproject.py", line 88, in _copytree
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 376, in copystat
    _copyxattr(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 326, in _copyxattr
    os.setxattr(dst, name, value, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/d/Scrapy/demo_pro/module/spiders'
```

Comment: Was this Scrapy 2.2.0? There’s a permissions issue fixed in 2.2.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scrapy does some things with file attributes that don't work on a Windows filesystem under WSL.

As a workaround, you could create the project on the WSL filesystem and then copy the result to where you want it.  Something along the lines of:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ scrapy startproject demo_pro
$ cp -r demo_pro /mnt/d/Scrapy
```